# Argument in the proof of theorem 4.2.3 of Ikeda and Watanabe

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

In page 163 of Ikeda and Watanabe (Stochastic Differential equations and Diffusion processes) one reads the following:

[image]

I must be missing something here, the authors say it's easy to see that $\sigma(t)\wedge \tilde{\sigma}_n = \sigma(t \wedge \sigma_n)$. I can't see why this is true.

**Context:**

$\bullet \tilde{X}:$

[image]

$\bullet \sigma:$

[image]

I have not found the deffinition of $\sigma_n$ but I guess it is $\sigma_n = \inf\{t >0\mid |X(t)|>n\}$ and

[image]

**Attempt:** The claimed equality seems true to me, since one could take $a = 0$, $b(x) = x$ and $\rho(x) = \frac{1}{2x} \wedge 1$. $X_0= 1 \Rightarrow \tilde{X}(t) = \frac{t}{2}+1$. Therefore:

\begin{align}\tilde{\sigma}_n &= 2(n-1)\\
A(t)&=\int_0^t \rho(\tilde{X}(s))\,ds = \int_0^t \frac{1}{2 + s}\, ds = \log(2 + t) - \log (2) = \log \tilde{X}(t)\\
\sigma(t) &= 2(e^t - 1)\\
X(t) &= \tilde{X}(2(e^t - 1))= e^t  \\
\sigma_n &= \log (n)\end{align}

the claim now is 
$$\sigma(t \wedge \sigma_n) = \sigma(t) \wedge \tilde{\sigma}_n \\
2 (\exp \{t \wedge \log (n)\} - 1) = 2(e^t - 1) \wedge  2(n-1)$$

Which is true for all $t >\sigma_n$.

But how can we prove that in general?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we just need to prove that $\sigma(\sigma_n) = \tilde{\sigma}_n$ and note that $\sigma$ is an increasing function. To see that $\sigma(\sigma_n) = \tilde{\sigma}_n$ consists in showing that

$$ \sigma_n  = \inf\{s > 0 \mid |\tilde{X}(\sigma(s))|> n\} = \sigma^{-1}\inf \{\sigma(s)>0 \mid |X(\sigma(s))|> n\} = \sigma^{-1} \tilde{\sigma}_n $$